# Offline support for lightning calendar

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

I created a network calendar and enabled offline support. However, starting thunderbird with no network-connection, the calendar doesn't show anything.
I expected that I would see my calendar entry.
Is this a bug oder do I expect the wrong thing? How can I debug this?
I'm using Thunderbird-Version: 60.2.1 (64-Bit) Lightning-Version: 6.2b6 with Linux Mint MATE 18.3

Comment: You can export your network calendar as an .ics file and open it locally. Why, though, would you expect a "network calendar" to be available without network connection??

Comment: Well, in practice: when travelling by train I have often lose network, nevertheless I want to know my dates. Beside, there's the option: Offline support (especially for network calendars in lightning), thus I expected it or want to know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

With Thunderbird 60.4.0 and Lightning 6.2.4 under GNU Linux system, I find a `~/.thunderbird/<id>.default/calendar-data/backup/` directory, in which I find several ICS calendars which seems to contain the offline information for my remote calendar.

So it seems that I can consult my remote calendar offline by *importing one of these ICS into a new calendar*.

It feels however silly to have to create a new calendar and manually do such import. I really wish the "offline support" of Lightning for remote calendars would provide a user-friendly (if not automatic) way to switch between remote server and offline local cached data.